# complexity and run time between sql and plpgsql functions

Tags: sql, postgresql

I recently read abou the [DO block](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-do.html).

It is known that SQL functions run faster than plpgsql functions. So if an operation can be done in SQL we would prefer doing it with SQL.

Now what about this situation?

```
create or replace function asql()
returns void as $$
    begin
        raise notice ''hello, world!';
    end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

AND:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION aplpgsql()
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$ 

DO language plpgsql $$
BEGIN
  RAISE NOTICE 'hello, world!';
END
$$;

$BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql
```

And what if I have more complex query other than just plain print?
the DO block allows to actualy always use SQL functions for anything, take all the `LOOPs` and `IFs` and put them in DO block.

What am I missing?

Comment: Wrapping a PL/pgSQL block inside a SQL function still makes the actually code that is executed PL/pgSQL. I can see no advantage at all in the second approach (plus you aren't able to return any result from the embedded PL/pgSQL block to the function).

Answer (score 0):

SQL functions are not faster than plpgsql function. Without inlining these functions are slower. Only when inlining was successful, then SQL fuctions are optically faster. What is inlining? Example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myleft(text, int) RETURNS text AS $$
  SELECT substring($1 FROM 1 FOR $2)
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

When you use function myleft, then a `rewriter` rewrites query

```
SELECT myleft('AHOJ',2)
```

to

```
SELECT substring('AHOJ FROM 1 FOR 2)
```

And the spead is same as native C function. But inlining is possible inly in some not too complex situations.

Wrapping PLpgSQL code to SQL function has only negative effect on performance.